# FCM Flutter IOS onLaunch/onResume not Working

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I would like to ask how to run onLaunch and onResume only onMessage is working in IOS(Using IOS 14 iPhone 11 Pro / Emulator), but all of the methods of FCM is working in Android

I tried many things have not worked even once, the things that have I tried:

- Reinstall IOS with part with pod cache clean --all new & denigrate then install
- trying this solution: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041#issuecomment-551431409, but it's not working
- trying to put this code inside fcm/send not working:

  ```
  "content_available": true,
     "mutable_content": true,
  ```
- setting `onBacgroundMessage: null` not working
- trying to edit AppDelegate.swift by putting import FirebaseMessaging ==> such method not found [this by trying to clean and install + hard code the Podfile
- Using step by step from this: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging, it's still not working
- Trying to use **console** from Application to track the FCM but it's still not showing inside the console, only onMessage is showing
- Have turn on the config of Xcode, but not working, even turn of the *Background Processing*: [image]

- Putting this inside AppDelegate.swift, but not working:

  ```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
          } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
          }
  ```

Here is my sample FCM code:

````
```

void configFirebase() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: _showFirebaseNotif,
        onBackgroundMessage: null,
        onResume: _showFirebaseNotif,
        onLaunch: _showFirebaseNotif);
  }

Future<void> _showFirebaseNotif(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print(message);
  }

```
````

Comment: Its simulator bug, use real device and it will be work

Comment: Ok will tried, thanks for the info

Comment: Nice after change to real device it's works, thx a lot

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Comment: yap, just used the real device than problem fixed for my case, because simulator get the return from firebase is different from real device, this make the BG can't show notifications in simulator